# Vaadin 8 History API and SEO

Tags: java, seo, vaadin, html5-history, vaadin8

How to properly use new Vaadin 8 HTML5 History API to manage my Views?
Can I use it with Navigator?
Currently I navigate in my apps by:    `getUI().getNavigator().navigateTo(viewName)`, but this is not SEO-freindly.
With History API I can do:

```
Page.getCurrent().pushState(viewName);
            Page.getCurrent().addPopStateListener(event -> {
            //something
            });
```

but it only change my  URI fragment without call listener(it is called when we use back/forward buttons in the browser).
On the other hand I can use

```
Page.getCurrent().pushState(viewName);
getUI().getNavigator().navigateTo(viewName);
```

but navigateTo method always add !# at the beggining.

I want to get History API functionality with navigator features.
On the Vaadin site is only one small example, without explain.

Answer (score 3):

The HTML5 History API does not work with the Navigator out of the box. But I've written an add-on that does this for you:
[HistoryApiNavigationStateManager Add-on](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/historyapinavigationstatemanager-add-on).

With that add-on you just create the special navigator and get the Html5 History API URLs you want.